# How to print the variable itself not a result?

Tags: scripting

Is there any way I can print the variable itself not a result ?

```
x=`curl -s https://google.com`
```

Expected Result

```
curl -s https://google.com
```

Can any one suggest a way to get the above result?

Thanks

Comment: use quotes instead of command substitution?  `x='curl -s https://google.com'`.  Seems like an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is never set to:

```
`curl -s https://google.com`
```

The command substitution happens before the variable assignment, and then the variable is assigned it's output.  I suppose you may be able to read from the file to get it:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=$(echo foobar)

awk -F\= '$1 == "x"{gsub(/\$\(|\)/, ""); print $2}' "$0"
```

Note you should use `$(...)` command substitution instead of backticks for many reasons, and you probably shouldn't do this at all.  If you tell us what your actual intent is there is surely a better solution.

---

You could also store your command in an array and use that for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

x=(echo foobar)

y=$("${x[@]}")

printf 'x is: %s\ny is: %s\n' "${x[*]}" "$y"
```

Which will output:

```
$ ./script.sh
x is: echo foobar
y is: foobar
```

Comment: Thank you
One more question, how to combine two variables e.g x y, become a command to execute

e.g
x=curl
y=google.com

I don't know the syntax. Thanks

Comment: @login: Short answer is **don't do that**.  Related: [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/237982)